# Apache Spark MLLib get maximum value

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I have the following model:

`case class Product(price:Int,distance:Int)`

and I have data that tells me if a customer is willing to buy the product for price x if distance is y (true/false).

I used a logistic regression in spark on it and can now predict (price,distance) pairs. What if I now want to know the maximum price I can charge for distance x?

code:

```
val products:List[(Product,Double)] = getProductVotes()
val points:List[LabeledPoints] = products.map{ case (product,vote) => 
        LabeledPoint(vote,Vectors.dense(product.price,product.distance)) }
val data: RDD[LabeledPoint] = sc.parallelize(points)
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1).cache()
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
    .setNumClasses(10)
    .run(training)
```

Comment: Can you add some code to your question? How are you achieving the prediction?

Answer (score 0):

To know the maximum price for a given distance X.

1. Take subset of your training data for which the vote=True
2. Build label point with label being "Price" and feature being "Distance"
3. Train a linear regression model on the set of labeled points to predict "Price" given the "Distance"